# Why the anonymous function is not getting an entire array or string passed as an argument to it in following program?

Tags: php, arrays, string, arguments, anonymous-function

Consider below working code :

```
<?php
  echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    /*Below var_dump() outputs
       array(2) {
         [0]=>
         string(2) "-w"
         [1]=>
         string(1) "w"
       }
    var_dump($match);*/
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
  }, 'hello-world');
  // outputs helloWorld
?>
```

The above code is working fine and generating the output. But I've some issue in understanding it's working in anonymous function.

My question is why the anonymous function is not getting the entire array or string which contains the value **helloWorld**?

Why it's getting the below weird array?

```
Array
(
  [0] => -w
  [1] => w
)
```

Comment: Your regex is not looking for whole words, but just a hyphen and a single letter.

Comment: I would expect that output.

Comment: @Badshah Can you explain your greater project task?  What would a larger / more realistic input string look like and what is the logic behind your process?  I'm interested in why you are capitalizing the letter after the hyphen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just adding another (probably redundant) answer, because I think you're mainly misunderstanding the task of the anonymous/callback function. ➜ It's supposed to to do pretty little.

Basically this is the logic flow:

1. Your input string is `'hello-world'`
2. Gets matched by [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)
3. And the regex only extracts `'-w'` from it.
4. Your callback function only receives that match, split into $match=`["-w", "w"]`
   <sup>(@mickmack already explained why)</sup>
5. The anonymous function is only supposed to work on the matched part / do its replacement magic with this excerpt.

   - It never works on, nor needs the whole original input (`hello-world`).
   - Since it is meant to just uppercase the first letter of the second word, working on `$match[1]` is sufficient.
   - It thusly only returns `'W'`
   - The job of the callback function **is not** to do its replacement on the whole / original string.
6. It is  [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) which does the actual **replacement task** on the input string.

   - It swaps out the regex-matched `'-w'` for the uppercase `'W'` as *returned* from your anonymous function.
   - As @ArtisticPhoenix explained, you could change the regex and match, and have your callback get a "better view" of the task at hand.

But again, for the actual purpose it's fully sufficient if your callback just sees the one letter and only returns that.

Answer (score 1):

Here I will explain it.

Your Regx  `'~-([a-z])~'` says:

- `-` literal, match `-` one time.
- `(..)` capture group, return results of the match.
- `[a-z]` character set, match `a` through `z` one time.

The callback's argument is based on the matches.  You get match `0` and `1`.  `0` is everything the Regx matches (including the `-`). The `1` is everything in the `first` capture group.

So when you give it `hello-world`, the match starts at the `-` and ends after the first `[a-z]` or in this case a `w`.

Now if you added another capture group, then you would have  match `2`. For example:

```
'~-([a-z])([a-z])~'
```

You would get something like `[0=>'-wo', 1=>'w',2=>'o']` instead.

Test it out, online, here: https://regex101.com/r/yakHNF/1

If you were to change it to

`'~-([a-z]+)~'`

It would give you `[0=>'-world', 1=>'world']`, because the `+` is match one or more times, so it matches the whole word.

Answer (score 1):

The "fullstring match" (the `[0]` element in the output array) is unavoidable.  What you *can* avoid (to reduce output array bloat and improve regex efficiency) is the use of a capture group.  You need to match the hyphen and the letter and only return the letter -- this way the hyphen is removed.

Here is an equivalent method without the output array bloat: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/561b7a9282d54d899e750fc973591f9681c704d8))

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~-[a-z]~', function ($match) {
    /*Below var_export() outputs only the "fullstring" match (no capture groups)
        array (
            0 => '-w',
        )
    var_export($match); */
    return strtoupper($match[0][1]);  // return only the character at offset 1 (2nd char)
  }, 'hello-world');
```

Output:

```
helloWorld
```